# Create dict try comprehension

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

This:

```
index ={}
for item in args:
    for array in item:
        for k,v in json.loads(array).iteritems():
            for value in v:
                index.setdefault(k,[]).append({'values':value['id']})
```

Works

But, when I try this:

```
index ={}
filt = {index.setdefault(k,[]).append(value['id']) for item in args for array in item for (k,v) in json.loads(array).iteritems() for value in v}
print filt
```

Output:

```
result set([None])
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: what is args here? an example will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*dict.setdefault* is an inplace method that returns None so you are creating a *set* of `None's` which as sets cannot have duplicates leave you with `set([None])`:

```
In [27]: d = {}

In [28]: print(d.setdefault(1,[]).append(1)) # returns None
None 
In [35]: d = {}

In [36]: {d.setdefault(k,[]).append(1) for k in range(2)} # a set comprehension 
Out[36]: {None}

In [37]: d
Out[37]: {0: [1], 1: [1]}
```

The *index* dict like d above would get updated but using any comprehension for side effects is not a good approach. You also cannot replicate the for loops/setdefault logic even using a dict comprehension.

What you could do is use a *defaultdict* with list.extend:

```
from collections import defaultdict

index = defaultdict(list)
for item in args:
    for array in item:
        for k,v in json.loads(array).iteritems():
            index[k].extend({'values':value['id']} for value in v)
```